# Usage of OData, WebApi routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have been playing with Webapi 2.0 and OData 2.0 for past 2 weeks. I would like to know as to when to use OData routing and Webapi Attribute routing.

Thanks,

Pavan

Answer (score 1):

Web API is a general framework for creating HTTP endpoints (web APIs/REST APIs). You can also use it to create OData endpoints, which is a more specific application of ASP.NET Web API.

So the first question is whether you want to create an OData endpoint or some other type of REST API.

If you are creating an OData endpoint, use OData routing. Otherwise use the "regular" Web API routing

Answer (score 1):

**Web API Routing**

you can use default routing but if you want to defined your route templates then you can used AtrributeRouting which is using convention-based routing
In this type of routing, you define one or more route templates, which are basically parameterized strings. 
When the framework receives a request, it matches the URI against the route template

install following nuget package :

```
"Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost"
```

Add following line in your "WebApiConfig.cs" file

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

create your webapicontroller like following

```
[Route("api/users")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetUsers(int userId)
    {
```

you can access your web api like this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/users/
```

**Web API Odata Routing**

when you want to use IQueryable instead of IEnumerable then you can use odata

install nuget package for odata

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData"
```

Add following code in your "WebApiConfig.cs" file

```
var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.EntitySet<ViewTest>("TestOdata");
var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
config.Routes.MapODataRoute(routeName: "OData", routePrefix: "odata", model: model);
```

Add following code in your "UsersOdataController.cs" file

```
public class TestOdataController : OdataController
    {
        //GET odata/TestOdata       
        public IQueryable<ViewTest> Get()
        {
            try
            {
                return context.View_TestRepository.GetQueryable();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               throw ex;               
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewTest : view model class with your required columns
View_TestRepository : Repository class

you can access your odata web api by following URL:

```
"http://localhost:8080/odata/TestOdata"
```